# Data in SQL not in proper date format, how to change it into the right format?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column called ProcessTimeOnHold that shows how long it takes us to process an order.

Any order that takes less than 24 hours to process is shown in this format `HH:MM:SS`. As far as I can tell this data is in the proper date format however any order that takes longer than 24 hours shows up in this format `D.HH:MM:SS`  So, if an order took 29 hours and 34 minutes it will show up as `1.05:34:00`.

The problem I have is if I try to convert or manipulate the data for example into minutes the orders in the proper data format will work but anything after 24 hours will return an error.

For example if I try to convert to minutes with this:

```
LTRIM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, ProcessTimeOnHold))
```

It will convert all orders into minutes until it runs into an order with the `D.HH:MM:SS` format and then it will return this error:

> Error Message: Conversion failed when converting datetime from
>   character string

Any way that I can change my entire column into datetime?

Comment: What type is ProcessTimeOnHold?

Comment: You can do it by parsing the string.   The string-functions in SQL Server are well documented.

Comment: The data type is nvarchar

Comment: Do you want to conver the `1.05:34:00` to minute or in `29:34:00`?

Comment: You can't use DATEDIFF or any of the other date related functions, because that's not a valid date format. (There is no SQL Server data type for `DAYS.HOURS:MINUTES:SECONDS`.) It's a string (NVARCHAR) of a made up format to represent your data. You'll need to write code (probably best a UDF) to parse that string and convert it into whatever other formats you need.

Comment: Preferably to number of minutes.

Comment: Long term solution always use the _correct_ datatype. In this case you should be using `datetime` (or one of the newer data types if you have a later version of SQL)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to search for a less verbose solution, but this is one option, using string manipulation:

```
  SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, (convert(time,RIGHT(ProcessTimeOnHold,8)))) + 
  (case when ProcessTimeOnHold like '%.%' 
         then  
         (cast((LEFT(ProcessTimeOnHold,CHARINDEX(ProcessTimeOnHold,'.')-1)) AS INT) * 24 * 60)
         else 0 end) as TotalMinutes
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm very new to SQL and I tried your code but I got an error message saying Type time is not defined.

Comment: what version of sql server are you using?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Comment: What does `SELECT @@version` return?

Answer (score 0):

(Edited based on comment)

Here's a way to get just the minutes:

```
declare @table table (ProcessTimeOnHold varchar(16));
insert @table (ProcessTimeOnHold)
values ('00:20:00')
     , ('01:20:00')
     , ('1.05:34:00');

select ProcessTimeOnHold
     , datediff(minute,0,right(ProcessTimeOnHold,8))
     + isnull(nullif(replace(left(ProcessTimeOnHold,charindex('.',ProcessTimeOnHold)),'.',''),''),0) * 1440 'Minutes'
  from @table

RETURNS:
ProcessTimeOnHold Minutes
----------------- -----------
00:20:00          20
01:20:00          80
1.05:34:00        1774
```

Comment: I think OP just want to return number of minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one- 
ANSI format: 2006.10.23
SELECT [ANSI]=CONVERT(char,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,102)